# Chart.js doughnut text visibility

Tags: reactjs, charts, chart.js

Chart.js doughnut text visibility. Tell me how to make it so that when the values intersect, the text comes out and changes its position.

```
const myChart = new Chart(canvas,
        {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                labels: dataNameDB,
                datasets: [{
                    data: dataCountDB,
                    backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                }],
            },
            plugins: [ChartDataLabels, DoughnutLabel],
            options: {
                cutout: 340,
                responsive: true,
                animation: false,

                plugins: {
                    legend: {
                        display: false,
                    },
                    datalabels: {
                        formatter: (val, ctx) => {
                            return Math.round((ctx.chart.data.datasets[0].data[ctx.dataIndex] * 100) / summChart()) + "%";
                        },
                        display: (val,ctx) =>{
                            return 'auto';
                        },
                        clamp: true,
                        clip: true,
                        anchor: 'center',
                        align: 'center',
                        offset: 1,
                        font: {
                            size: 65,
                            weight: 'bold',
                            color: '000000'
                        },
                        color: '000000',
                        labels: {
                            value: {
                                color: '#000000'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    doughnutlabel: {
                        labels: [{
                            text: summChart,
                            font: {
                                size: 140,
                                weight: 'bold',
                                color: '000000'
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    );
```

[image]

Now it outputs something like this, but I need it to be like this:

[image]

Although the documentation says that display `'auto'` is responsible for this, how to catch it when the text is hidden in order to move it?

Comment: Take a look at `chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels`, maybe this helps.